# Clauset-Newman-Moore community detection implementation

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, modularity

I am trying to implement the above community detection algorithm in Java, and while I have access to C++ code, and the original paper - I can't make it work at all. My major issue is that I don't understand the purpose of the code - i.e. how the algorithm works. In practical terms, my code gets stuck in what seems to be an infinite loop at `mergeBestQ`, the list `heap` seems to be getting larger on each iteration (as I would expect from the code), but the value of `topQ` is always returning the same value.

The graph I am testing this on is quite large (300,000 nodes, 650,000 edges). The original code I am using for my implementation is from the SNAP library (https://github.com/snap-stanford/snap/blob/master/snap-core/cmty.cpp). What would be great is if someone could explain to me the intuition of the algorithm, it seems to be initially setting each node to be in it's own community, then recording the modularity value (whatever that is) of each pair of connected nodes in the graph, then finding the pair of nodes which have the highest modularity and moving them to the same community. In addition, if someone could provide some mid level pseudo code, that would be great. Here is my implementation thus far, I have tried to keep it in one file for the sake of brevity, however CommunityGraph and CommunityNode are elsewhere (should not be required). Graph maintain a list of all nodes and each node maintains a list of its connections to other nodes. When running it never gets past the line `while(this.mergeBestQ()){}`

UPDATE - found several bugs in my code after a thorough review. The code now completes VERY quickly, but doesnt fully implement the algorithm, for example of the 300,000 nodes in the graph, it states there are approximately 299,000 communities (i.e. roughly 1 node per community). I have listed the updated code below.
    /// Clauset-Newman-Moore community detection method.
    /// At every step two communities that contribute maximum positive value to global modularity are merged.
    /// See: Finding community structure in very large networks, A. Clauset, M.E.J. Newman, C. Moore, 2004
    public class CNMMCommunityMetric implements CommunityMetric{
      private static class DoubleIntInt implements Comparable{
        public double val1;
        public int val2;
        public int val3;
        DoubleIntInt(double val1, int val2, int val3){
          this.val1 = val1;
          this.val2 = val2;
          this.val3 = val3;
        }

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(DoubleIntInt o) {
      //int this_sum = this.val2 + this.val3;
      //int oth_sum = o.val2 + o.val3;
      if(this.equals(o)){
        return 0;
      }
      else if(val1 < o.val1 || (val1 == o.val1 && val2 < o.val2) || (val1 == o.val1 && val2 == o.val2 && val3 < o.val3)){
        return 1;
      }
      else{
        return -1;
      }
      //return this.val1 < o.val1 ? 1 : (this.val1 > o.val1 ? -1 : this_sum - oth_sum);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
      return this.val2 == ((DoubleIntInt)o).val2 && this.val3 == ((DoubleIntInt)o).val3;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      int hash = 3;
      hash = 79 * hash + this.val2;
      hash = 79 * hash + this.val3;
      return hash;
    }
  }

  private static class CommunityData {
    double DegFrac;
    TIntDoubleHashMap nodeToQ = new TIntDoubleHashMap();
    int maxQId;

    CommunityData(){
      maxQId = -1;
    }

    CommunityData(double nodeDegFrac, int outDeg){
      DegFrac = nodeDegFrac;
      maxQId = -1;
    }

    void addQ(int NId, double Q) { 
      nodeToQ.put(NId, Q);
      if (maxQId == -1 || nodeToQ.get(maxQId) < Q) { 
        maxQId = NId;
      } 
    }

    void updateMaxQ() { 
      maxQId=-1; 
      int[] nodeIDs = nodeToQ.keys();
      double maxQ = nodeToQ.get(maxQId);
      for(int i = 0; i < nodeIDs.length; i++){
        int id = nodeIDs[i];
        if(maxQId == -1 || maxQ < nodeToQ.get(id)){
          maxQId = id;
          maxQ = nodeToQ.get(maxQId);
        }
      } 
    }

    void delLink(int K) { 
      int NId=getMxQNId(); 
      nodeToQ.remove(K); 
      if (NId == K) { 
        updateMaxQ(); 
      }  
    }

    int getMxQNId() { 
      return maxQId;
    }

    double getMxQ() {
      return nodeToQ.get(maxQId); 
    }
  };
  private TIntObjectHashMap<CommunityData> communityData = new TIntObjectHashMap<CommunityData>();
  private TreeSet<DoubleIntInt> heap = new TreeSet<DoubleIntInt>();
  private HashMap<DoubleIntInt,DoubleIntInt> set = new HashMap<DoubleIntInt,DoubleIntInt>();
  private double Q = 0.0;
  private UnionFind uf = new UnionFind();
  @Override
  public double getCommunities(CommunityGraph graph) {
    init(graph);
    //CNMMCommunityMetric metric = new CNMMCommunityMetric();
    //metric.getCommunities(graph);
    // maximize modularity
    while (this.mergeBestQ(graph)) {
    }
    // reconstruct communities
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> IdCmtyH = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
    Iterator<CommunityNode> ns = graph.getNodes();
    int community = 0;
    TIntIntHashMap communities = new TIntIntHashMap();
    while(ns.hasNext()){
      CommunityNode n = ns.next();
      int r = uf.find(n);
      if(!communities.contains(r)){
        communities.put(r, community++);
      }
      n.setCommunity(communities.get(r));
    }
    System.exit(0);
    return this.Q;
  }

  private void init(Graph graph) {
    double M = 0.5/graph.getEdgesList().size();
    Iterator<Node> ns = graph.getNodes();
    while(ns.hasNext()){
      Node n = ns.next();
      uf.add(n);
      int edges = n.getEdgesList().size();
      if(edges == 0){
        continue;
      }
      CommunityData dat = new CommunityData(M * edges, edges);
      communityData.put(n.getId(), dat);
      Iterator<Edge> es = n.getConnections();
      while(es.hasNext()){
        Edge e = es.next();
        Node dest = e.getStart() == n ? e.getEnd() : e.getStart();
        double dstMod = 2 * M * (1.0 - edges * dest.getEdgesList().size() * M);//(1 / (2 * M)) - ((n.getEdgesList().size() * dest.getEdgesList().size()) / ((2 * M) * (2 * M)));// * (1.0 - edges * dest.getEdgesList().size() * M);
        dat.addQ(dest.getId(), dstMod);
      }
      Q += -1.0 * (edges*M) * (edges*M);
      if(n.getId() < dat.getMxQNId()){
        addToHeap(createEdge(dat.getMxQ(), n.getId(), dat.getMxQNId()));
      }
    }
  }
  void addToHeap(DoubleIntInt o){
    heap.add(o);
  }

  DoubleIntInt createEdge(double val1, int val2, int val3){
    DoubleIntInt n = new DoubleIntInt(val1, val2, val3);
    if(set.containsKey(n)){
      DoubleIntInt n1 = set.get(n);
      heap.remove(n1);
      if(n1.val1 < val1){
        n1.val1 = val1;
      }
      n = n1;
    }
    else{
      set.put(n, n);
    }
    return n;
  }
  void removeFromHeap(Collection<DoubleIntInt> col, DoubleIntInt o){
    //set.remove(o);
    col.remove(o);
  }
  DoubleIntInt findMxQEdge() {
    while (true) {
      if (heap.isEmpty()) {
        break; 
      }

      DoubleIntInt topQ = heap.first();
      removeFromHeap(heap, topQ);
      //heap.remove(topQ);
      if (!communityData.containsKey(topQ.val2) || ! communityData.containsKey(topQ.val3)) {
        continue; 
      }
      if (topQ.val1 != communityData.get(topQ.val2).getMxQ() && topQ.val1 != communityData.get(topQ.val3).getMxQ()) { 
        continue; 
      }
      return topQ;
    }
    return new DoubleIntInt(-1.0, -1, -1);
  }
  boolean mergeBestQ(Graph graph) {
    DoubleIntInt topQ = findMxQEdge();
    if (topQ.val1 <= 0.0) { 
      return false; 
    }
    // joint communities
    int i = topQ.val3;
    int j = topQ.val2;
    uf.union(i, j);

    Q += topQ.val1;
    CommunityData datJ = communityData.get(j);
    CommunityData datI = communityData.get(i);
    datI.delLink(j);
    datJ.delLink(i);

    int[] datJData = datJ.nodeToQ.keys();
    for(int _k = 0; _k < datJData.length; _k++){
      int k = datJData[_k];
      CommunityData datK = communityData.get(k);
      double newQ = datJ.nodeToQ.get(k);
      //if(datJ.nodeToQ.containsKey(i)){
      //  newQ = datJ.nodeToQ.get(i);
      //}
      if (datI.nodeToQ.containsKey(k)) { 
        newQ = newQ + datI.nodeToQ.get(k);
        datK.delLink(i);
      }     // K connected to I and J
      else { 
        newQ = newQ - 2 * datI.DegFrac * datK.DegFrac;
      }  // K connected to J not I
      datJ.addQ(k, newQ);
      datK.addQ(j, newQ);
      addToHeap(createEdge(newQ, Math.min(j, k), Math.max(j, k)));
    }

    int[] datIData = datI.nodeToQ.keys();
    for(int _k = 0; _k < datIData.length; _k++){
      int k = datIData[_k];
      if (!datJ.nodeToQ.containsKey(k)) { // K connected to I not J
        CommunityData datK = communityData.get(k);
        double newQ = datI.nodeToQ.get(k) - 2 * datJ.DegFrac * datK.DegFrac; 
        datJ.addQ(k, newQ);
        datK.delLink(i);
        datK.addQ(j, newQ);
        addToHeap(createEdge(newQ, Math.min(j, k), Math.max(j, k)));
      }
    } 
    datJ.DegFrac += datI.DegFrac; 
    if (datJ.nodeToQ.isEmpty()) { 
      communityData.remove(j); 
    } // isolated community (done)
    communityData.remove(i);
    return true;
  }
}
```

UPDATE:the currently listed code is fairly quick, and has half the memory usage compared to the "quickest" solution, while only being ~5% slower. the difference is in the use of hashmap + treest vs priority queue, and ensuring only a single object for a given i, j pair exists at any time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So [here's](http://www.ece.unm.edu/ifis/papers/community-moore.pdf) the original paper, a neat lil' six pages, only two of which are about the design & implementation. Here's a cliffnotes:

- For a partition of a given graph, the authors define the *modularity*, `Q`, of the partition to be the ratio of the number of edges *within* each community to the number of edges *between* each community, minus the ratio you'd expect from a completely random partition.
- So it's effectively "how much better is this partition at defining communities than a completely random one?"
- Given two communities `i` and `j` of a partition, they then define `deltaQ_ij` to be how much the modularity of the partition would change if communities `i` and `j` were merged. So if `deltaQ_ij > 0`, merging `i` and `j` will improve the modularity of the partition.
- Which leads to a simple greedy algorithm: start with every node in its own community. Calculate `deltaQ_ij` for every pair of communities. Whichever two communities `i, j` have the largest `deltaQ_ij`, merge those two. Repeat.
- You'll get maximum modularity when the `deltaQ_ij` all turn negative, but in the paper the authors let the algorithm run until there's only one community left.

That's pretty much it for understanding the algorithm. The details are in how to compute `deltaQ_ij` quickly and store the information efficiently.

Edit: Data structure time!

So first off, I think the implementation you're referencing does things a different way to the paper. I'm not quite sure how, because the code is impenetrable, but it seems to use union-find and hashsets in place of the author's binary trees and multiple heaps. Not a clue *why* they do it a different way. You might want to email the guy who wrote it and ask.

Anyway, the algorithm in the *paper* needs several things from the format `deltaQ` is stored in:

- First, it needs to be able to recover the largest value in `dQ` quickly.
- Second, it needs to be able to remove all `deltaQ_ik` and `deltaQ_ki` for a fixed `i` quickly.
- Third, it needs to be able to update all `deltaQ_kj` and `deltaQ_jk` for a fixed `j` quickly.

The solution the authors come up to for this is as follows:

- For each community `i`, each **non-zero** `deltaQ_ik` is stored in a [balanced binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_binary_tree), indexed by `k` (so elements can be found easily), and in a heap (so the maximum for that community can be found easily).
- The maximum `deltaQ_ik` from each community `i`'s heap is then stored in *another* heap, so that the overall maximums can be found easily.

When community `i` is merged with community `j`, several things happen to the binary trees:

- First, each element from the `i`th community is added to the `j`th community's binary tree. If an element with the same index `k` already exists, you sum the old and new values.
- Second, we update all the remaining "old" values in the `j`th community's binary tree to reflect the fact that the `j`th community has just increased in size.
- And for each other community's binary tree `k`, we update any `deltaQ_kj`.
- Finally, the tree for community `i` is thrown away.

And similarly, several things must happen to the heaps:

- First, the heap for community `i` is thrown away.
- Then the heap for community `j` is rebuilt from scratch using the elements from the community's balanced binary tree.
- And for each other community `k`'s heap, the position of entry `deltaQ_kj` is updated.
- Finally, the entry for community `i` in the overall heap is thrown away (causing bubbling) and the entries for community `j` and each community `k` connected to `i` or `j` are updated.

Strangely, when two communities are merged there's no reference in the paper as to removing `deltaQ_ki` values from the `k`th community's heap or tree. I think this might be dealt with by the setting of `a_i = 0`, but I don't understand the algorithm well enough to be sure.

Edit: Trying to decipher the implementation you linked. Their primary datastructures are

- `CmtyIdUF`, a union-find structure that keeps track of which nodes are in which community (something that's neglected in the paper, but seems necessary unless you want to reconstruct community membership from a trace of the merge or something),
- `MxQHeap`, a  heap to keep track of which `deltaQ_ij` is largest overall. Strangely, when they update the value of a `TFltIntIntTr` in the heap, they don't ask the heap to re-heapify itself. This is worrying. Does it do it automatically or something?
- `CmtyQH`, a hashmap that maps a community ID `i` to a structure `TCmtyDat` which holds what looks heap of the `deltaQ_ik` for that community. I think. Strangely though, the `UpdateMaxQ` of the `TCmtyDat` structure takes linear time, obviating any need for a heap. What's more, the `UpdateMaxQ` method only appears to be called when an element of the heap is deleted. It should definitely also be getting called when the value of any element in the heap is updated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I am actually going into a meeting with my supervisor (who requested this work) so will look over it in detail. But in short, no I haven't tried it on smaller graphs - we have the Q value from the original implementation for this graph, so I had hoped that by having that value we would know if it was correct. Also, I am not very familiar with heaps or balanced trees. I am using a TreeSet in Java along with a comparator that ensures the last entry in the set is the largest. I think balanced tree refers to the union find, which I have implemented (correctly I think)

Comment: It's 11pm in the UK, so a full answer will have to wait for tomorrow, but: a treeset is not a heap, and union-find is (afaik) little to do with balanced trees, it's a heuristic for a set data structure. Anyway, you shouldn't be implementing your own datastructures - there's too much that can go wrong. In this case, Java already implements a heap in its PriorityQueue type. Edit: If you haven't already, read Pt II of the paper. Even if you don't have much of a mathematical background, it shouldn't be too hard to follow.

Comment: No worries, I'm trying it now with a priority queue. the balanced tree part of UF is to ensure the height of the tree never exceeds log(n)

Comment: I actually got this working today, it executes in 1 minute, finds a similar Q and set of coms to the original (not identical for reasons I wont get into), it does have ENORMOUS memory usage. Over 2GB. This is because of this line: `heap.add(new DoubleIntInt(newQ, Math.min(j, k), Math.max(j, k)));` it creates a new entry for `j, k` that overwrites the old entry, (for the same j,k) but because the priority queue isnt a hashed priority queue, a new record gets added (should overwrite the existing one). 20 second slowdown reduces memory by50%using hashmap to maintain a "pool" of existing j,k pairs

Comment: Good timing, just woke up! Okay, so by "balanced tree" I think you mean "union by rank". That's different. [A balanced binary tree is a different sort of algorithm entirely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_binary_tree). Give me two minutes, I'm gonna update my post with some information on the data structures in this algorithm.

Comment: that is good timing, FYI - I got the overhead down to 5% (2 seconds) and still a reduction of nearly 50% on memory usage. Its interesting because the implementation I used as a model used UnionFind.

Comment: ugh, on second thoughts its 4am in Canada - I gotta get some sleep - I'll read through this in the AM - thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey Andy, I'm going to move this to chat if you don't mind, couple of other questions/comments - but yes its mostly working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43082/discussion-between-zack-newsham-and-andy-jones)

Comment: how do you handle the case of a tie or many equal values of max deltaQ?